# How to create docker multiarch manifest using cirrus-ci?

Tags: docker, multiarch, cirrus-ci

I am trying to build a multiarch manifest with [Cirrus CI](https://cirrus-ci.com), so I need to enable the [docker experimental option](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/cli/experimental/README.md)
But the experimental option of docker is not taking into account.

In the .cirrusci.yml I have something like:

```
publish_docker_builder:
  script: | 
    mkdir -p $HOME/.docker
    echo '{ "experimental": "enabled" }' > $HOME/.docker/config.json
    docker info
    docker login --username=$DOCKERHUB_USER --password=$DOCKERHUB_PASS 
    docker manifest create --amend $CIRRUS_REPO_FULL_NAME:latest $CIRRUS_REPO_FULL_NAME:linux  $CIRRUS_REPO_FULL_NAME:rpi  $CIRRUS_REPO_FULL_NAME:windows
```

But the execution reports :

> ```
> mkdir -p $HOME/.docker
> echo '{ "experimental": "enabled" }' > $HOME/.docker/config.json
> ....
> Labels:
> Experimental: false
> ....
> docker manifest create is only supported on a Docker cli with experimental cli features enabled
> ```

The full log is https://api.cirrus-ci.com/v1/task/6577836603736064/logs/main.log

Is this a limitation on dockerd available in Cirrus CI or I made some wrong configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker cli seems to have changed the way to enable experimental feature [cli](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/)

> DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL Enable experimental features for the cli (e.g.
>   enabled or disabled)

Adding to the .cirrusci.yml :

```
  env:
    DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL: enabled
```